# X11 screencasting multicasting solution

Tags: x11, multicast, nomachine-nx

I need to multicast an x11 application window to multiple (sai 100) clients in a lossy (wireless) environment.

Right now, I was able to do it through screen grabbing (vlc) and h264 compression, but there should be a cleaner solution, something along the lines of a multicast NX session.

Is there anything which could work with some glue, or should I build something for the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i.e. TightProjector from the TightVNC project:

http://www.tightvnc.com/projector/

I would try merging Vinagre (VNC Server) and Vino (VNC Client) with OpenPGM (reliable multicast),

- http://projects.gnome.org/vinagre/
- http://launchpad.net/vino
- http://openpgm.googlecode.com/

Ideally you should be able to find a stable bitrate and setup pro-active FEC to help overcome packet loss.